# Where can I find a worknig fedoracoin wallet for Windows?

Tags: wallet, windows

I downloaded the fedora coin wallet but when I open the file it says “file incomplete or damaged”. I download it from fedoracoin web site more than ten times with the same outcome.

So where can I download a wallet that will work for Windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

Try to "run as administrator".